# Fastest way to check if an image contain any (semi)transparent pixels?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Does anyone know is there a better way to check if some image contain a (semi)transparent pixel beside going trough all pixels and check their alpha channel?

```
[pseudo]
    for each pixel in image:
        if pixel.alpha != 0xff:
            return true
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [BufferedImage.getType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29)
or
[ColorModel.hasAlpha()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html#hasAlpha%28%29)
to check if there is an alpha channel.

If there is an alpha channel, you will have to check the individual pixels.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a better way than simply iterating all pixels. if you already have a mip-map stored for the alpha channels you can check from top to bottom for any non-opaque pixels.

JAI supports these: put the alpha channel or the whole image into a [javax.media.jai.ImageMIPMap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/ImageMIPMap.html) then iterate its levels from top to bottom using [getImage(int level)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/ImageMIPMap.html#getImage%28int%29)

some keywords for googling: [gauss-laplace image pyramids, mipmaps](http://dev.imagejdev.org/gbh/javaimaging/Mipmap.html)